# When reloading sections, footer is not displayed in UIViewCollectionView

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

Basically I have a button on the footer of a section that shows more cells in that particular section. However, I have a problem when I perform :

> `[self.friendsCollectionView reloadSections:sectionSet];`

The footer seems to disappear after the reload.  Also, when you scroll down a bit, it will re-appear. I am also using flowlayouts to manage my cells.

Also, I am on landscape mode so I am assuming after the increase, the flow layouts are not updated. Since collectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:atIndexPath is not even called.

Anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `invalidateLayout` on your layout before calling `reloadSections:`. That will cause the layout to be re-applied after the sections are redrawn, which should cause your footer to redraw.